# Admin textarea input field for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, textarea, backend

I am looking for a way to add texarea custom input for woocommerce general tab.
I already try `woocommerce_wp_text_input` but it shows one line input. Is there any way to add multiple
line input under the general tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `woocommerce_wp_textarea_input` opposite `woocommerce_wp_text_input`

So you get:

```php
// Add field
function action_woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data() {
    // Textarea Field
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
        'id'          => '_my_field_id',
        'label'       => __( 'My label', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => true,
        'description' => __( 'Some description', 'woocommerce' ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'action_woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 10, 0 );

// Save Field
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['_my_field_id'] ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_my_field_id', esc_html( $_POST['_my_field_id'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the existing [`woocommerce_wp_textarea_input()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/admin/wc-meta-box-functions.php#L96-L139) function instead.

[Related treads with `woocommerce_wp_textarea_input()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_wp_textarea_input).